# Marmalade Quick: wait until animation ends

Tags: lua, marmalade

I have a tween animation, and I need to launch a function with parameters after it completes.

I was unable to find any sleep command in Lua without loading the CPU, but then the animation freezes. I tried `onComplete`, but it doesn't wait for the animation to end and it executes that function right after the delay timer is over (just when the animation starts).

I have been looking for a solution for 3 hours straight, but I was unable to find anything. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marmalade quick [includes luasocket](http://quick-docs.madewithmarmalade.com/api/Socket.html), which has a [sleep function](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/socket.html#sleep).

**Update**

Another options could be setting up a [timer](http://quick-docs.madewithmarmalade.com/api/System.html#system%3aaddTimer__X.X.X.X) and let the timer fire your function after the delay you need.

Comment: Have you tried to use it with sub-second timings? Its argument is in second, but IIRC you can specify 0.02 (or whatever) as argument (it doesn't have to be an integer).

Comment: 0.02 seconds works,  but I need to pause it for a longer time (about 1 sec) I tried to loop it, but animation glitches and/or app crashes. Probably, it needs to be called after tween ends, but for some reason onComplete does not work correctly

Comment: I tried it, but it does not allow to call a function with params

Comment: Wrap the function call in a closure, i.e. use `function() myFunction(1,2,"hello") end` as the function to be called.